# Aggregate() example in R

Tags: r, aggregate

I was looking at the help page for the `aggregate` function in R. I had never used this convenience function but I have a process it should help me speed up. However, I've been totally unable to walk through the example and understand what is going on.

One example is the following:

```
1> aggregate(state.x77, list(Region = state.region), mean)
         Region Population Income Illiteracy Life Exp Murder HS Grad  Frost   Area
1     Northeast       5495   4570      1.000    71.26  4.722   53.97 132.78  18141
2         South       4208   4012      1.738    69.71 10.581   44.34  64.62  54605
3 North Central       4803   4611      0.700    71.77  5.275   54.52 138.83  62652
4          West       2915   4703      1.023    71.23  7.215   62.00 102.15 134463
```

The output here is exactly what I would expect. So I try to understand what is going on. So I look at `state.x77`

```
1> head(state.x77)
           Population Income Illiteracy Life Exp Murder HS Grad Frost   Area
Alabama          3615   3624        2.1    69.05   15.1    41.3    20  50708
Alaska            365   6315        1.5    69.31   11.3    66.7   152 566432
Arizona          2212   4530        1.8    70.55    7.8    58.1    15 113417
Arkansas         2110   3378        1.9    70.66   10.1    39.9    65  51945
California      21198   5114        1.1    71.71   10.3    62.6    20 156361
Colorado         2541   4884        0.7    72.06    6.8    63.9   166 103766
```

OK, that's odd to me. I would expect to see a column in state.x77 named `state.region` or something. So state.region must be its own object. So I do a str() on it:

```
1> str(state.region)
 Factor w/ 4 levels "Northeast","South",..: 2 4 4 2 4 4 1 2 2 2 ...
```

It looks like state.region is just a factor. Somehow there HAS to be a connection between state.region and state.x77 in order for aggregate() to group state.x77 by state.region. But that connection is a mystery to me. Can you help me fill in my obvious misunderstandings?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From an old tampon (was it tampons?) commercial: "Proof, not only promises!"

```
state.x777 <- as.data.frame(state.x77)
state.x777 <- cbind(state.x777, stejt.ridzn = state.region)
aggregate(state.x77, list(Region = state.x777$stejt.ridzn), mean)
```

Answer (score 4):

They are likely in the correct order as these objects are documented on the same help page `?state.x77`, which has:

```
Details:

     R currently contains the following “state” data sets.  Note that
     all data are arranged according to alphabetical order of the state
     names.
```

Comment: Doh! I forgot the data has help pages.

Answer (score 1):

Try `help(state.region)` etc --- they are all aligned:

> Details:
>
> ```
>  R currently contains the following “state” data sets.  Note that
>  all data are arranged according to alphabetical order of the state
>  names.
> ```